# table.insert in Lua 5.1.5 causes program to crash

Tags: lua

I have a function that worked well when I called it from directly global table but caused a crash when I called the function from a local function, which initializes a GUI using wxLua. After going through line by line, I realized that `table.insert` was causing the application to completely crash.

My code is:

```
--prepare a 3D table
for i=1, size(v2) do
    tbl[i]={}
    for j=1,size(v1) do
        tbl[i][j]={}
    end
end

for k=1, size(yobs) do
    local i,j=0, 0
    repeat i=i+1 until x2(k)==v2(i)
    repeat j=j+1 until x1(k)==v1(j)
    table.insert(tbl[i][j],yobs(k))
end
```

The above code caused a crash, right at `table.insert`. I have changed the code in the following way and it works well now.

```
for k=1, size(yobs) do
    local i,j=0, 0
    repeat i=i+1 until x2(k)==v2(i)
    repeat j=j+1 until x1(k)==v1(j)
    local pos=#tbl[i][j]
    if(pos==nil) then tbl[i][j][1]=yobs(k) else tbl[i][j][pos+1]=yobs(k) end     
end
```

I was wondering if there is a known bug for `table.insert` function. I am using Lua 5.1.5 compiled with tdm-gcc 4.8.1 running on Windows 10.

Comment: `#tbl[i][j]` is never `nil`

Comment: Try to check your Lua with [standard Lua tests](https://www.lua.org/tests/)

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff: You are right, `#tbl[i][j]` so far never been `nil`

Comment: What kind of crash? A clean error with a Lua message or a segfault?

Comment: @lhf: There was no error message at all, I am assuming it was segfault